# How to add woocommerce custom order status?

Tags: php, wordpress, function, woocommerce

I have added new custom order status to woocommerce by using following function.

```html
// Register New Order Statuses
function wpex_wc_register_post_statuses() {
 register_post_status( 'wc-custom-order-status', array(
  'label'      => _x( 'Shipping In Progress', 'WooCommerce Order status', 'text_domain' ),
  'public'     => true,
  'exclude_from_search'  => false,
  'show_in_admin_all_list' => true,
  'show_in_admin_status_list' => true,
  'label_count'    => _n_noop( 'Approved (%s)', 'Approved (%s)', 'text_domain' )
 ) );
}
add_filter( 'init', 'wpex_wc_register_post_statuses' );

// Add New Order Statuses to WooCommerce
function wpex_wc_add_order_statuses( $order_statuses ) {
 $order_statuses['wc-custom-order-status'] = _x( 'Shipping In Progress', 'WooCommerce Order status', 'text_domain' );
 return $order_statuses;
}
add_filter( 'wc_order_statuses', 'wpex_wc_add_order_statuses' );
```

whenever I go to edit order and changed the order status to newly added custom order status and click on Save Order button. After loading the order status automatically changes to Pending Order not stands in newly added custom order...

[image]

[image]

How to overcome this problem...?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The order status that you're registering `wc-custom-order-status` is too long - `22` characters. This results in saving only the first 20 characters of the post status, which makes it invalid and causes your issue.

The order statuses are registered as post statuses, and post statuses have a limitation of `20` characters.

I suggest that you update your `wc-custom-order-status` status name to `wc-shipping-progress`, which is exactly `20` characters in length.

I'm also posting the updated version of your code, just for reference (I've only changed the status name):

```
// Register New Order Statuses
function wpex_wc_register_post_statuses() {
    register_post_status( 'wc-shipping-progress', array(
        'label'                     => _x( 'Shipping In Progress', 'WooCommerce Order status', 'text_domain' ),
        'public'                    => true,
        'exclude_from_search'       => false,
        'show_in_admin_all_list'    => true,
        'show_in_admin_status_list' => true,
        'label_count'               => _n_noop( 'Approved (%s)', 'Approved (%s)', 'text_domain' )
    ) );
}
add_filter( 'init', 'wpex_wc_register_post_statuses' );

// Add New Order Statuses to WooCommerce
function wpex_wc_add_order_statuses( $order_statuses ) {
    $order_statuses['wc-shipping-progress'] = _x( 'Shipping In Progress', 'WooCommerce Order status', 'text_domain' );
    return $order_statuses;
}
add_filter( 'wc_order_statuses', 'wpex_wc_add_order_statuses' );
```

Comment: Thanks! If I could I would double like your answer.

Comment: 'This results in saving only the first 20 characters of the post status' Thanks!!! Days of struggle with this issue!

Comment: I know this is 5 years old, but this solved the issue I had with the order status not saving.