# Change backend created booking orders to a custom status in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, orders, woocommerce-bookings

When creating an order with a booking in backend, the order status is set to pending, but I want the booking order created to be set to a custom order status that uses `service-booked` as slug, on order creation.

How can I change backend created booking orders to a custom status in WooCommerce?

Comment: Do you want to change the slug of custom post type?

Comment: I want to change booking order status slug when i create  new booking

Comment: @shivanijoshi  Check my answer - That is what you are searching for?

Comment: I want to change order status while creating Booking, with the help of your code Booking Status Changed but after creating order for Booking ,Booking status changed when i changed booking order status manually from back end. @mujeeburahman

Comment: So it's working for front end orders and not for backoreders?

Comment: I want to change order status for bookable product pending to service booked when i Add new booking for product. By default order status displays pending payment. I want to change that order status to service booked when i Add new booking from backend @mujeeburahman

Comment: When editing the price on a product in the admin order/backend, I want to edit the set the total price incl VAT. Not the price excl VAT as now. How Can i Achive this ? @mujuonly

Comment: Already Price Inclusive Tax is set in woocommerce  product setting . I want to set Inclusive Product Price instead of price exclusive vat while i edit order in backend @mujuonly

Comment: yes, while editing order from admin in woocommerce  currently price and inclusive VAT displayed  in different column. i want  to display price with Inclusive Tax in price column and make it editable.@mujuonly

Comment: I want to add custom meta field in product search in admin in  wordpress. How can i achieve this ? @mujuonly

Comment: @shivanijoshi - similar examples here -https://stackoverflow.com/a/32163516/1117368

Comment: I want to search using ptoduct gtin number in woocommerce product-search @mujuonly

Comment: https://gist.github.com/mujuonly/db0ae2366d191e9aaee212592b60ed80

Comment: I added code from gist.github.com/mujuonly/db0ae2366d191e9aaee212592b60ed80 but product not displaying while searching using gtin number in order.@mujuonly

Comment: I want to search using product GTIN number in admin order while adding new item in woocommerce. How can i achieve it? @mujuonly

Comment: Please accept below answer if it helped, and add this comment as a new question- So I can answer @shivanijoshi

Comment: which below answer  ? @mujuonly

Comment: @shivanijoshi Answer of this question by me  "Change backend created booking orders to a custom status in WooCommerce"

Answer (score 0):

```
add_action( 'init', 'register_my_new_order_statuses' );

function register_my_new_order_statuses() {
    register_post_status( 'wc-service-booked', array(
        'label'                     => _x( 'Service Booked', 'Order status', 'woocommerce' ),
        'public'                    => true,
        'exclude_from_search'       => false,
        'show_in_admin_all_list'    => true,
        'show_in_admin_status_list' => true,
        'label_count'               => _n_noop( 'Service Booked <span class="count">(%s)</span>', 'Service Booked<span class="count">(%s)</span>', 'woocommerce' )
    ) );
}

add_filter( 'wc_order_statuses', 'my_new_wc_order_statuses' );

// Register in wc_order_statuses.
function my_new_wc_order_statuses( $order_statuses ) {
    $order_statuses['wc-service-booked'] = _x( 'Service Booked', 'Order status', 'woocommerce' );

    return $order_statuses;
}

add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_pending', 'mysite_processing');
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_processing', 'mysite_processing');

function mysite_processing($order_id){
     $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );

     if ( ! $order ) {
        return;
     }

     // Here you can check the product type in the order is your booking                     
     //   product and process accordingly
     // update status to service booked
     $order->update_status('service-booked'); 

}
```

**Tested OK** with **WooCommerce 3.5.5** and **WordPress 5.1**

Answer (score 0):

The following will change the order status from **`processing`** to your custom status **`service-booked`**, if a bookable product is in the order:

```
// Change the order status from 'pending' to 'service-booked' if a bookable product is in the order
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_changed', 'bookable_order_custom_status_change', 10, 4 );
function bookable_order_custom_status_change( $order_id, $from, $to, $order ) {
    // For orders with status "pending" or "on-hold"
    if( $from == 'pending' || in_array( $to, array('pending', 'on-hold') ) ) :

    // Get an instance of the product Object
    $product = $item->get_product();

    // Loop through order items
    foreach ( $order->get_items() as $item ) {
        // If a bookable product is in the order
        if( $product->is_type('booking') ) {
            // Change the order status
            $order->update_status('service-booked');
            break; // Stop the loop
        }
    }
    endif;
}
```

Code goes on function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). It shoul works.

---

To add a custom order status `service-booked` use one of the following existing answers:

- [How to add woocommerce custom order status?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29789680/how-to-add-woocommerce-custom-order-status)
- [Add custom order status to filter menu in WooCommerce Admin Orders list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53346544/add-custom-order-status-to-filter-menu-in-woocommerce-admin-orders-list)

Comment: When i created booking, order status for booking is pending not processing i changed status pending instead of processing as per above code but still order status displays pending not service -booked.

Comment: @shivanijoshi I have updated the code… Did you use Woocommerce Bookings plugin? It's not clearly specified in your question and my code works for bookable products in an order using Woocommerce bookings plugin…

Comment: yes, I am using woocommerce booking plugin. but, above code returns 500 server error when i put it in child theme's functions.php file . @loictheaztec

Comment: @shivanijoshi Updated… Sorry there was a missing bracket… Try it again please.

Comment: I want to change order  status for bookable product pending to service booked when i Add new booking for product. By default order status displays pending payment. I want to change that order status to service booked when i Add new booking. @lioctheaztec